# Read two columns, compare 2nd column values based on condition, write final result into new table

Tags: sql-server-2012, insert, compare, conditional-statements

I have a table, `Groups`, which has two columns, `Group_Name` and `Criticality`.

```
Group_Name  Severity
-------------------
Group 1     LOW
Group 2     MEDIUM
Group 2     LOW
Group 3     LOW
Group 3     HIGH
Group 3     MEDIUM
Group 4     LOW
Group 4     MEDIUM
Group 4     LOW
Group 4     MEDIUM
```

I now want to create a table which will have the final severity details. Like

```
Group_Name  Final_Severity
-------------------
Group 1     LOW
Group 2     MEDIUM
Group 3     HIGH
Group 4     MEDIUM
```

The comparison condition is to check what is the highest severity type assigned for each group - L < M < H.

For example, considering the `Group 3`, as there are 3 severity types assigned, the comparison should return `H` as the final severity for the selected group `Group 3`.

And finally write all these values into the a (final) table as mentioned above.

How can I do this in SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, this query will give you result you wnt:

```
select Group_name, Severity from (
    select Group_name, Severity,
           ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by group_name order by [level] desc) [rn]
    from MY_TABLE [t] join
    --here we assign numeric values to severities to make it comparable
    (values ('LOW', 1),('MEDIUM', 2),('HIGH', 3)) as Severity([name], [level]) on [t].Severity = [Severity].name
) a where rn = 1
```

Comment: @Shreesha I copied your data and it worked. You must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Michal. This worked very well and I'm able to see the result I was looking at.

Comment: @Shreesha I am pleased to hear that, also accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Yes, Michal. There was a typo in table name that I gave so I was getting empty table in return. Corrected that and this worked. Many thanks.

Comment: Done. :) Cheers!